# Error: The 'super-parameters' language feature is disabled for this library

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/elevated_button.dart:67:14: Error: The 'super-parameters' language feature is disabled for this library.

Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.17 or higher.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwl4G.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM10I.png)

I suspect that the problem appeared after Android Studio updated to Dolphin version

Answer (score 0):

There's something weird going on here. You've likely got two versions of the Dart SDK installed (a >= 2.17 SDK through Flutter, one < 2.17 standalone) with  the older version on your PATH. The Flutter SDK ships with its own Dart SDK and should only be using language features that are supported by the SDK shipped with it, so you should never seen this error normally.

Make sure you don't have two SDKs installed, or at least make sure that the SDK that's shipped with Flutter is first on your path.